# Converting into Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, linq

Can anyone help me convert this to a Lambda form

```
double abc = (from x in y
select (new Employee(x)).Name).SomeMethod();
abc = Math.Double(abc/1000, 2.0);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
double abc = y.Select(x => new Employee(x).Name)
              .SomeMethod();
```

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you after?

```
var abc = y.Select(x =>  new Employee(x).Name).SomeMethod();
abc = Math.Double(abc/1000, 2.0);
```

Comment: Looks like the second call to abc was removed from the question. Now your answer looks confusing.

Comment: I didn't remove it. 'dtb' did. Thanks for the answer

Comment: @Matt Kraven: Indeed. Because you were asking about the LINQ expression, not the surrounding code. BTW, there is no Math.Double method in the [Math Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.aspx).